# Get licenses by user from License Manager API

Tags: google-admin-sdk

Is there any endpoint to get all the licenses assigned to an specific user? like this one:

GET https://www.googleapis.com/apps/licensing/v1/product/productId/sku/skuId/user/userId

but without {productId} and {skuId}, to receive the licenses actives for the user.